# Is there any stable serialization method for different languages?

Tags: java, c++, serialization, cryptography, protocol-buffers

In my project we have an API, and many clients may send transactions to this API. Transactions should be signed. Clients may be written in any language (C++, C#, python, go, whatever), with any CPU architecture and endianness.

The problem now is to serialize our Transaction model into bytes, in order to be able to sign and then send it.

---

Our team selected protobuf v3.3.0 (proto syntax = proto3) for this purpose.

We wanted to use envelope pattern, which looks like:

```
message SignedTransaction {
  message Transaction {/* any data that should be signed */}
  Transaction transaction = 1;
  Signature signature = 2;
}
```

To sign, we just serialize internal object Transaction:

```
Transaction tx = <...>;
std::string bytes = tx.SerializeAsString();
// and then sign bytes
```

---

The problem with protobuf now is that it seems it is not deterministic for different languages. Today we wrote simple proto file with few integers and string, filled with the same data, serialized it for different languages and observed results.

We tried Javascript, C++, Java, Swift and it turned out that everything except C++ produces the same output string:

JavaScript, Java, Swift produced: `08B90A10BA0A1A106C6F6C206B656B20636865627572656B`

C++ produced: `8FFFFFFB9A10FFFFFFBAA1A106C6F6C206B656B20636865627572656B`

C++ `parseFromString(str)` is able to deserialize string from other languages, but not vice versa.

Questions are:

1. Why C++ protobuf produces different string?
2. What libraries can we use for our use case?

---

Details:

```
// test.proto:
syntax = "proto3";
package api;

message Msg {
    uint32 a = 1;
    int32  b = 2;
    string c = 3;
    bytes  d = 4;
}

// test.cpp:
api::Msg msg;

msg.set_a(1337);
msg.set_b(1338);
msg.set_c("lol kek cheburek");

std::string str = msg.SerializeAsString();
// str = 8FFFFFFB9A10FFFFFFBAA1A106C6F6C206B656B20636865627572656B
```

Comment: I believe that a good universal way of serialization is JSON. But of course, it is not a binary format, it is a text format.

Comment: Asking recommendations for libraries or other off-site resources is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Something is wrong. Show in longer code way you use. Protobuf, and few protocols in this class, work very well between languages  (and I suppose problem has nothing to C allingments like Marcin say)

Comment: Few proven binary protocol exist: thrift, protobuf, hessian, avro and others. You are not the first inter-language developer on the market. To be strict, I develop and use interlanguage solution Apache Thift few years, works vetry well

Comment: @JacekCz thanks. I will look at Apache Thrift. 

To be honest there is nothing to show in my code. It does exactly what you expect: creates proto message, fills fields and serializes proto. For every language.

Comment: XDR, GIOP, XML, JSON, ...

Comment: Your code doesn't show any of the `SignedTransaction` stuff you mentioned. Is that part actually relevant to the problem? And do you ever set `bytes d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my code which prints hexstring had bug in it. [details](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3570)

*Short answer*:
Protobuf is a stable serialization method and can be used for described use case.

Answer (score 1):

[what is serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization_(disambiguation))

I think protobuf is confusing with the term serialization. What protobuf does is rather a special kind of encoding. This besides

I suspect NOT setting `b` will cause the problem. This mean the value of b is uninitialized. java objects are automatically initialized with zeros, c++ object does no automatic initialization which mean the content may be just random values. And the may happen to `b`

Comment: can agree with Your changed answer (mostly)

Comment: Instead of linking to a Wikipedia article you should either link an on-site resource or give a brief explanation yourself. Linking to off-site resources is strongly discouraged, as you should know already.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf is not stable in the sense that the same object in memory can be serialized in different ways. Mainly because when an object has several fields, the fields can be serialized in any order.

See doc here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#implications .